# Date returns NaN in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I try to convert UTC Time string to Local Time. In my function the sate retun Nan in IE but works on FF & Chorome.

```
var myDate = '2016-12-17 4:20';
var LocDate = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(new Date(myDate));
console.log(LocDate);
```

Output(IE): NaN-aN-aN aN:aN

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
  if(typeof date !== undefined){
    var locDate,iYear,iMonth,iDay,iMin;
    var newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
    iYear = newDate.getFullYear();
    iMonth = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
    iDay = newDate.getDate();
    iHrs = newDate.getHours();
    iMin = newDate.getMinutes();
    locDate = iYear + '-' + ('0' + iMonth).slice( - 2) + '-' + ('0' + iDay).slice( - 2) + ' ' + ('0' + iHrs).slice( - 2) + ':' + ('0' + iMin).slice( - 2);
    return locDate;
  }
}
```

How to fix for IE?

Comment: which jQuery version ?

Comment: ...nothing to do with jQuery. Edited your question again.

Comment: why don't you use `toLocaleDateString()` native method? please explain exactly what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: jquery version 1.7.2

Comment: toLocaleDateString() method converts the date (not the time) of a Date object into a readable string and need both @ vsync

Comment: so why did you call your method `convertUTCDateToLocalDate` if that is not what you want it to do? you want something like `convertUTCToCustomDate`